# Vue separation of concerns causes Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am new to vue and trying to separate my ts/scss from the main vue file.
I am using kebab-casing as stated in the styleguide and because it's familiar to me:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Single-file-component-filename-casing-strongly-recommended

Here is my app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <the-header @onExpanded="setExpanded($event)" />
    <router-view />
    <the-footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script src="./app.ts" lang="ts"></script>
<style src="./app.scss" lang="scss"></style>
```

As you can see I am including my **app.ts** and **app.scss**.
In my TypeScript file I have this:

```
import { defineComponent, ref } from "@vue/composition-api";
import { useQuery, useResult } from "@vue/apollo-composable";

import * as pageCollection from "@/graphql/query.pages.gql";
import TheFooter from "@/components/layout/the-footer/the-footer";
import TheHeader from "@/components/layout/the-header/the-header";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: { TheFooter, TheHeader },
  setup() {
    const expanded = ref(false);
    const { result } = useQuery(pageCollection);
    const pages = useResult(result, null, (data) => data.pageCollection);

    return { expanded, pages };
  },
  methods: {
    setExpanded(value: boolean) {
      this.expanded = value;
      console.log(this.expanded);
    },
  },
});
```

Here I am trying to include my header and footer.
My folder structure looks like this (with part of the-header.vue):

[image]

Here is my header TypeScript:

```
import { defineComponent, ref } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "TheHeader",
  setup() {
    const isExpanded = ref(false);

    return { isExpanded };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isExpanded: false,
    };
  },
  emits: ["onExpanded"],
  methods: {
    expand() {
      this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
      this.$emit("onExpanded", this.isExpanded);
    },
  },
});
```

The problem is, when I try to run the application. I get this error:

[image]

The console log at the bottom is actually from my footer, which tells me it is finding the component fine. Is there something else I need to do in order to get the components to render?

Comment: where is the template (or render function) for the header?

Comment: the template is in the-header.vue

Comment: What do your template and script look like for `the-footer`?

Comment: you didn't show that, nor import it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the import in **app.ts**, it is currently:

```
import TheFooter from "@/components/layout/the-footer/the-footer";
import TheHeader from "@/components/layout/the-header/the-header";
```

abut should be:

```
import TheFooter from "@/components/layout/the-footer/the-footer.vue";
import TheHeader from "@/components/layout/the-header/the-header.vue";
```